# Python dbase in to mysql

Tags: php, python, ubuntu-11.04

I have application in ubuntu named school tool it uses **zodb** . I want to change format of database into csv or i want to import structure into mysql

Any Body have any idea how to do this

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [SQLAlchemy](http://readthedocs.org/docs/sqlalchemy-migrate/en/latest/) docs for `migrate` and perhaps that can help you.